# context_processor with if inside

Tags: django, view, model, choicefield

first of all ,
thanks for all the answers that have permit me to get better at django, i'm not yet an "uber" djanglers but i'm moving forward.
I'll got a problem with a project.
As i'll move into django i'll keep being stuck with the same problem:
I got django allauth installed to have several field in registration for a horse club
in this fields i'll have a choices field, with the mount level.
here is the model code :

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    PRIME = (
        ('régulier', 'régulier'),
        ('occasionnel', 'occasionnel'),
        ('concours', 'concours'),
    )

    NIVEAUX = (
        ('débutant', 'débutant'),
        ('galop1', 'Galop 1'),
        ('galop2', 'Galop 2'),
        ('galop3', 'Galop 3'),
        ('galop4', 'Galop 4'),
        ('galop5', 'Galop 5'),
        ('galop6', 'Galop 6'),
        ('galop7', 'Galop 7'),
    )

    AGE = (
        ('18 mois - 3ans', '18mois - 3ans'),
        ('3 - 5 ans', '3 - 5 ans'),
        ('6 - 12 ans', '6 - 12 ans'),
        ('13 - 60 ans', '13 - 60 ans'),
    )

    PHOTO =(
        ('oui', 'oui'),
        ('non', 'non'),
    )
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length= 120)
    nom = models.CharField(max_length= 120)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ville = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    code_postal = models.IntegerField(default="63120")
    occurence = models.CharField(choices=PRIME ,max_length = 150, default='régulier')
    niveaux = models.CharField(choices=NIVEAUX ,max_length = 150, default='débutant', help_text="Quel niveau validé avez vous obtenus ? ")
    age = models.CharField(choices=AGE ,max_length = 150, default='18 mois - 3ans', help_text=" A quelle tranche d'age allez vous appartenir ?")
    photo = models.CharField(choices=PHOTO ,max_length = 150, default='oui', help_text=" Acceptez vous d'être photographié ?")
```

and i'll got a blog that will show  post to everyone and to people inside a specific level ("niveaux")
the actual problem i'll have is to make the view that will and this into all page, so i'll go to the idea of a context_processor I have tried this as context processor :

```
from .models import News
from accounts.models import CustomUser
from django.conf import settings

def galopage(request):
    #creer les variables de groupes
    group1 = CustomUser.objects.filter(niveaux='débutant')
    group2 = CustomUser.objects.filter(niveaux='galop1')
    group3 = CustomUser.objects.filter(niveaux='galop2')
    group4 = CustomUser.objects.filter(niveaux='galop3')
    group5 = CustomUser.objects.filter(niveaux='galop4')
    group6 = CustomUser.objects.filter(niveaux='galop5')
    group7 = CustomUser.objects.filter(niveaux='galop6')
    group8 = CustomUser.objects.filter(niveaux='galop7')

    if group1 == True:
        niveaux = News.objects.filter(choix='débutant')
        return {'retourgroup': niveaux}

    elif group2 == True:
        niveaux = News.objects.filter(choix='galop1')
        return {'retourgroup': niveaux}

    elif group3 == True:
        niveaux = News.objects.filter(choix='galop2')
        return {'retourgroup': niveaux}

    elif group4 == True:
        niveaux = News.objects.filter(choix='galop3')
        return {'retourgroup': niveaux}

    elif group5 == True:
        niveaux = News.objects.filter(choix='galop4')
        return {'retourgroup': niveaux}

    elif group6 == True:
        niveaux = News.objects.filter(choix='galop5')
        return {'retourgroup': niveaux}

    elif group7 == True:
        niveaux = News.objects.filter(choix='galop6')
        return {'retourgroup': niveaux}

    elif group8 == True:
        niveaux = News.objects.filter(choix='galop7')
        return {'retourgroup': niveaux}

    else:
        pass
```

and i'll have this as answer :
Module "News.context_processors" does not define a "request" attribute/class

the blog part :

```
    from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):
    NIVEAUX = (
        ('visiteur', 'visiteur'),
        ('débutant', 'débutant'),
        ('galop1', 'galop1'),
        ('galop2', 'galop2'),
        ('galop3', 'galop3'),
        ('galop4', 'galop4'),
        ('galop5', 'galop5'),
        ('galop6', 'galop6'),
        ('galop7', 'galop7'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField()
    choix = models.CharField(choices=NIVEAUX, max_length=15, default='visiteur')
    
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

(i'll added 'News.context_processors.request', to context processors)

This is a problem i'll encounter a large number of time in several project,
I can't get a solution for this and i'll feel really dumb about it.

Thanks for your time and consideration,
Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

if News is your app name (basically "app_name.context_processors.function_name"), then you should add

```
"News.context_processors.galopage"
```

into your 'context_processors' which is under TEMPLATES of settings.py

Comment: Well i'll tried that but it is not working, the sad part that i m not sure that the best way to achieve what i'll need, i need to show the post from the blog with choice by example "galop1" to user with 'galop1' in table field... any idea that would be easier perhaps ?